# Using Nuget Package Explorer to build packages

Tags: nuget

I just created a class library and wanted to push up it to our internal Nuget repository.

Suppose the url is `http://Mycompany:81/nuget/default`

How to do it with GUI(Nuget Package Explorer)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To publish using NuGet Package Explorer:

1. Select Publish from the File menu.
2. Enter your NuGet feed url and api key.